# Android Barcode scanner in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2x Fragments in an Activity each filling half of the screen (top/bottom).

I need to have a barcode(QR) scanner running in the top fragment and then display the scanned data in the bottom fragment while the scanner continues running in the top.

The problem I am facing is that I cannot find a way to run ZXING scanner in a fragment, it always starts in an Activity filling the whole screen.

Please point me in the right direction.